# `ggplot2`: label values of barplot that uses `fun.y="mean"` of `stat_summary`

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I use `ggplot2`'s `stat_summary()` to make a barplot of the average number of miles per gallon for 3-, 4-, and 5-geared cars, for example, how can I label each of the bars with the average value for mpg?

```
library(ggplot2)
CarPlot <- ggplot() +
  stat_summary(data= mtcars,
               aes(x = factor(gear),
                   y = mpg,
                   fill = factor(gear)
                   ),
               fun.y="mean",
               geom="bar"
               )
CarPlot
```

I know that you can normally use `geom_text()`, but I'm having trouble figuring out what to do in order to get the average value from `stat_summary()`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should use the internal variable `..y..` to get the computed mean.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
CarPlot <- ggplot(data= mtcars) +
               aes(x = factor(gear),
                   y = mpg)+
      stat_summary(aes(fill = factor(gear)), fun.y=mean, geom="bar")+
      stat_summary(aes(label=round(..y..,2)), fun.y=mean, geom="text", size=6,
             vjust = -0.5)
CarPlot
```

but probably it is better to aggregate beforehand.

Comment: Why is it better to aggregate beforehand?

Comment: @Adam because you have closer control of what you are doing and you have more flexibility. Also you can use the same aggregation in another plot, summary,report,...

Comment: Also, in the call above the summary is calculated twice, once for each call to `stat_summary`. For small datasets, this might not be a problem, but for larger datasets it might.

Comment: This solution ended up working nicely for my problem, so I'm going to go ahead and accept it, but I appreciate the discussion about pre-aggregation, agstudy and @PaulHiemstra. I'll keep that in mind in the future. And thanks for your solution, too, Paul.

Comment: is it possible to produce the same result hiding the legend bar on the side? thanks

Comment: Is there some documentation about the internal variables (e.g. `..y..`)? The ggplot2 book only mentions "the old `..var..` notation": ggplot2-book.org/internals.html

Answer (score 6):

I'd simply precompute the statistics, and build the plot afterwards:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat = ddply(mtcars, .(gear), summarise, mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
dat = within(dat, {
    gear = factor(gear)
    mean_mpg_string = sprintf('%0.1f', mean_mpg)
  })
ggplot(dat, aes(x = gear, y = mean_mpg)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = gear), stat = "identity") + 
    geom_text(aes(label = mean_mpg_string), vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: you can do it simpler, `ggplot(ddply(mtcars, .(gear), summarise, mean_mpg = mean(mpg)), mean_mpg_string = sprintf('%0.1f', mean_mpg))+ geom_bar(..`

Comment: I don't really like stacking all functions together in one giant function call. You end up having to split the function up into multiple lines for readability, making the advantage of one function call compared to making several function calls small. In addition, in this way the summary stats are also available for other functions, e.g. making a table.

Comment: I totaly agree for the stacking fact(ggplot+ddply), But you can still compute mean_mpg and mean_mpg_string with the same ddply...`ddply(mtcars, .(gear), summarise, mean_mpg = mean(mpg), mean_mpg_string = sprintf('%0.1f', mean_mpg))`

Comment: @agstudy That is definitely true, it all boils down a bit to a matter of taste I guess.