# ggplot: How to add labels to stat_summary_bin (not stat_summary)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I'm able to create a stat_summary_bin with each x bin (a continuous variable) showing the avg value of y like below. How can I add y value labels, showing the avg y value per bin above each bin?

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price, y=carat)) +
  stat_summary_bin(fun.y = "mean",
                   geom="bar",
                   binwidth=5000
                   )
```

[image]

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139978/ggplot2-label-values-of-barplot-that-uses-fun-y-mean-of-stat-summary) which uses stat_summary() doesn't resolve my question. When I tried the solution there, it didn't handle the binwidths correctly.

```
ggplot(diamonds,
       aes(x=price, y=carat, label=round(..y..,2))
       ) +
  stat_summary_bin(fun = "mean",geom="bar", binwidth=5000) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean",geom="text",binwidth=5000)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same solution for `stat_summary` works for `stat_summary_bin`

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price, y=carat, label=round(..y..,2))) + 
  stat_summary_bin(fun = "mean",geom="bar", binwidth=5000) + 
  stat_summary_bin(fun = "mean",geom="text",binwidth=5000, vjust=-0.5)
```

[image]

Tested with `ggplot2_3.3.2`. Note that `fun.y` is deprecated and the help page encourages you to use `fun` instead.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. The solution provided in the answer marked as duplicate is substantially different because of the use of a different function and because of how the arguments are passed due to this question being about stat_summary_bin. This solution may be obvious for expert users, but for newer ggplot users it may not be the case.

Comment: As you noted, the other answer is also using outdated code suing `fun.y`.

Comment: Were you looking at the answer from "agstudy"? I don't see how that's substantially different. Using his exact same syntax but swapping `stat_summary_bin` for `stat_summary` also works: `ggplot(data= diamonds) + aes(x = price, y = carat)+ stat_summary_bin(fun.y=mean, geom="bar", binwidth=5000)+ stat_summary_bin(aes(label=round(..y..,2)), fun.y=mean, geom="text", vjust = -0.5, binwidth=5000)`. If you are going to ask a second question, you should at least updated your code to show how you attempted to use the existing answer. (it still works with `fun.y`, you just get a warning.)

Comment: I added code for how the solution in the other answer didn't work for me initially.

Comment: OK. Sure. If you want binning then you need to use `stat_summary_bin`. The point of that answer is that you can retrieve the calculated value with `..y..` (or with `stat(y)`) and map it to what ever aesthetic you like. All the same `ggplot` rules apply. But note that since you have two layers you are preforming all the expensive calculations twice. It would be much more efficient to summarize before plotting.